# How to normalize-scale data in attribute in range <-1;1>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Hello i have used many options for normalize data in my dataframe attribute elnino_1["air_temp"] ,but it always shows me an error like *"Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."* or "*'int' object is not callable*" .

I try this code:
(1)

```
elnino_1["air_temp"].min=-1
elnino_1["air_temp"].max=1
elnino_1_std = (elnino_1["air_temp"] - elnino_1["air_temp"].min(axis=0)) / (elnino_1["air_temp"].max(axis=0) - elnino_1["air_temp"].min(axis=0))
elnino_1_scaled = elnino_1_std * (max - min) + min
```

(2)

```
XD=elnino_1["air_temp"]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
```

In both option I use libraries:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn import preprocessing
```

What I should to do for normalize this data please?
[image: Type of Attribute air_temp]

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have access to your dataset, here I'm using `make_classification` to generate some synthetic data. Please run through in a notebook to gain understanding. (Do note as well there may be slight differences as I'm using a numpy array as dataset, yours is a DataFrame.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=1)

pd.DataFrame(X).head()
```

Thereafter, we fit a `MinMaxScaler` to the data. MinMaxScaler accepts a 2d array as input by default. In other words, a 'table'. Throughout these, please call `X.shape` to understand how array shapes work. For e.g in the above, `X.shape >> (100, 2)` where it is (numrows, numcolumns)

```py
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))

X_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X)

pd.DataFrame(X_norm).head()
```

In your case, you are only trying to fit/scale a single column. When you only fit `elnino_1["air_temp"]` it is a 1d array, shape is something like (100,).

So we have to reshape it into a 2d array.

```py
x1_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X[:, 1].reshape(-1,1))
pd.DataFrame(x1_norm)
```

For example, if `xyz.shape` is (100,) and I want it to be (100,1), I can use `xyz.reshape(100,1)` if I'm being specific.

The length of the dimension set to -1 is automatically determined by inferring from the specified values of other dimensions. This is useful when converting a large array shape. Thus `xyz.reshape(-1,1)` achieves the same as above.